# NA won't omit in R when 0 is between 1's

Tags: r, list, function, matrix, dataframe

I am suppose to change a square matrix which represents a graph (the vertices-and-edges kind) and change it into a list that represents the same graph

square matrix: element (i,j) = 1 means there is an edge i -> j
list: element i is a vector (possibly empty, coded as NA) of all j s.t. there is an edge i -> j
My problem is that if there is a zero in the middle of the row it returns a NA and it is only suppose to do that when a vector is empty(no edges). It only does it when a zero is between two 1's. I don't know why and NA.omit doesn't work.
This is my first time programming in R.

```
 squaretolist <- function(m){
        ml <- list() #creates an empty list that we will return at the end 
        for(i in 1:ncol(m)){ #loop through columns
            b1 <- c()
            for(j in 1:nrow(m)){ #loop through rows
                ifelse(m[i,j] %in% 1, b1[j] <- j, next)
            }
            ifelse(length(b1) == 0, ml[[i]]<- NA, ml[[i]] <- b1 )
        }
        return(ml)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function, if you have a zero in between two 1s, for example 1 in the 1st position and in the 3rd position, you're assigning `b1[1]` to 1, `b1[3]` to 3 but, as you have a 0 in the 2nd position, you're not assigning `b1[2]` to anything so it becomes `NA`.

To avoid that, you can replace `ifelse(m[i,j] %in% 1, b1[j] <- j, next)`
by `ifelse(m[i,j] %in% 1, b1 <- c(b1,j), next)`.

You can also get what you want with the use of `grep` and `apply` functions :

```
ml <- apply(m, 1, function(i) {if(any(i==1)) grep(1, i) else NA})
```

This instruction tells `R` to apply, for each row of the matrix `m`, a function that returns, if there is at least one `1`, the position of the `1(s)`, else `NA`.

**Example:**

```
set.seed(123)
m<-matrix(sample(c(0,1),25,replace=T),nrow=5)
m[4,]<-rep(0,5)

# > m
     # [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    0    0    1    1    1
# [2,]    1    1    0    0    1
# [3,]    0    1    1    0    1
# [4,]    0    0    0    0    0
# [5,]    1    0    0    1    1         

ml<-apply(m,1,function(i){if(any(i==1)) grep(1,i) else NA})
  # > ml
    # [[1]]
    # [1] 3 4 5

    # [[2]]
    # [1] 1 2 5

    # [[3]]
    # [1] 2 3 5

    # [[4]]
    # [1] NA

    # [[5]]
    # [1] 1 4 5
```

Comment: Sweet thanks! Yeah I ended up changing it to just that!